# ESP32 Guru Meditation Error while using .substring method

Tags: arduino, esp32

So I have written a function for my ESP32 using the Arduino IDE, and I needed to write a function to take a combined string of hex values like this:

```
ffffff0000ffff0000
```

And split it into an array, like this:

```
{"ffffff","0000ff","ff0000"}
```

So far, I've written this:

```
String colorIndex[] = {};

void processColors(String input){

  int count = 0;
  
  for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i += 6){

    colorIndex[count] = input.substring(i,i+6);
    count++;
  };

  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(colorIndex); i++){
    Serial.println(colorIndex[i]);
  }
  
}
```

But, I've run into a problem where whenever this function is run, the Serial port prints out this error:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (StoreProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x4000c3f5  PS      : 0x00060830  A0      : 0x800d9575  A1      : 0x3ffd2eb0  
A2      : 0x00000050  A3      : 0x3ffd2f10  A4      : 0x00000007  A5      : 0x0000ff00  
A6      : 0x00ff0000  A7      : 0xff000000  A8      : 0x00000000  A9      : 0x00000050  
A10     : 0x00000066  A11     : 0x3ffd3696  A12     : 0x00000007  A13     : 0xed62d3d8  
A14     : 0x06000000  A15     : 0x06000000  SAR     : 0x00000010  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001d  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000050  LBEG    : 0x400014fd  LEND    : 0x4000150d  LCOUNT  : 0xfffffffe  

Backtrace: 0x4000c3f5:0x3ffd2eb0 0x400d9572:0x3ffd2ed0 0x400d967a:0x3ffd2ef0 0x400d1283:0x3ffd2f10 0x400d1322:0x3ffd2f40 0x400d7345:0x3ffd2f80 0x400d51e9:0x3ffd2fc0 0x400d5279:0x3ffd3000 0x400d8369:0x3ffd3020 0x400d83e9:0x3ffd3060 0x400d89fa:0x3ffd3080 0x40088b7d:0x3ffd30b0

Rebooting...
```

I googled it, and found that this error is caused by an illegal access to memory. What is causing this and what can I do to fix it? Or, is there a better way to do the task that I wish to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `colorIndex` to be an empty array of `String`.

```
String colorIndex[] = {};
```

to be an empty array, and then you start storing things in it... but you haven't reserved any place to store them. So when you try to save a `colorIndex` substring in your loop, it's written somewhere random and causes the exception you're seeing.

You can verify this easily by just eliminating the assignment like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i += 6){

    Serial.println(input.substring(i,i+6));
  };
```

you should see the substrings you extracted and not get the error.

You need to declare `colorIndex` to have enough space for however many items you're going to store in it. For instance, if you know that you'll never have more than 3 strings in it, you'd write:

```
String colorIndex[3] = {};
```

To protect your code from accidentally overflowing the array, you should really test the index in your loop. In that case, your code should look more like:

```
#define MAX_COLOR_INDICES 3

String colorIndex[MAX_COLOR_INDICES] = {};


void processColors(String input){

  int count = 0;
  
  for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i += 6){
    if(count == MAX_COLOR_INDICES) {
      Serial.printf("ran out of room for color indices at %d\n", count);
      break;
      }

    colorIndex[count] = input.substring(i,i+6);
    count++;
   };
```